# Subscribe to observable and await later

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Following would NOT catch the emitted value:

```
someObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern(this, "MyEvent");
FireMyEvent("foo");
await someObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Args == "foo");
```

So I've come across this pattern in my unit tests:

```
var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

var callback = someObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);

using (callback.Subscribe(e => tsc.SetResult(e.Args)))
{
    FireMyEvent("foo");
    tsc.Task.Wait(1000);
}
Assert.AreEqual("foo", tsc.Task.Result);
```

Basically I need to subscribe, then trigger the action and then await the subscribed observable.

Is it possible to simplify this subscribe/await without introducing new Task, or WaitHandle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but if I understand the basic idea then this works:

```
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();

var callback = subject.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

using (callback.Subscribe(_ => { }, () => Console.WriteLine("Done.")))
{
    subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
}
```

Can you explain your use-case more fully?

Comment: Yeah, but I need to wait until the FirstOrDefault() returns the value, otherwise I cannot do the assert, or whatever logic. My problem is with the awaiting, not with emitting the value

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't really understand your assumption, that the await won't catch the result.
2. You have to await the event before it gets fired

`someObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern(this, "MyEvent");
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ => FireMyEvent("foo"));
var result = await someObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Args == "foo");`

Your result ist now a EventPattern. However I would recommend a more type safer FromEventPattern-Overload:

```
var eventObservable = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<YourEventArgs>(
                h => MyEvent += h,
                h => MyEvent -= h);
```